# Setting up luks encrypted drive to automount

Tags: ubuntu, luks, ubuntu-18.04

So I'm trying to setup my luks encrypted drive which holds the root partition to automount on server start. I'm having an issue where it doesn't automount and instead prompts for a passphrase.

```
lsblk Output:
sda5
|_sda5_crypt
  |_srv--vg-root    lvm   /
  |_srv--vg-swap_1  lvm [SWAP]

/etc/crypttab:
sda5_crypt UUID=uuid goes here /boot/keyfile luks,discard

/etc/fstab:
/dev/mapper/srv--vg-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Now I know that I'm supposed to create a new entry like

```
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt / ext4 defaults 0 2
```

but my / is already defined in fstab, how do I add the crypt entry to fstab so it knows to mount it so the lvm volume groups can be mounted on boot?

Comment: You must enter at least one password, otherwise what would be the point of an encrypted drive? You can auto-mount other partitions because their keys are kets in the first partition which isn't auto-mounted. One can also wonder what is the point of encrypting a server?  Are you expecting it to be stolen with sensitive data on it?

Comment: LUKS supports using keyfiles, and /boot is accessible outside of the encrypted partition. I know it's not the best solution, but this is for a client and unfortunately, it's what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Does it prompt for a password at boot? If so, then it is already trying to automount the partition, but the keyfile is unavailable / incorrect. You could try specifying the partition the keyfile is on by changing the path to `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid>:/keyfile`